# SQL Server stored procedure script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am wondering if I can modify a generated script to copy data from 1 database to another. I used the "Generate scripts" tool and can I then take the latest run each time and create a stored procedure to then take latest tables and insert that into new database?

Source tables have an extension of `_dateinfo`. So table called `ABC_05162016` would be on next run table `ABC_06162016`. Is there a way to take the original generated script and then update that last part 1 time instead of constantly selecting all the tables every time this is needed to be done?

Thanks for the help. Yes I have looked around for an answer to this but have not come across something like this. All deal with importing/exporting data or using Generated Script part. Thanks for the help.

If there is a better way then those 3 ways. I would appreciate knowing that as well.

Using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Are you saying that you have dBSource and dbDestination. dBSource has tables like ABC_05162016 and you need to sync it to dBDestination?

Comment: No. I want to know if it is possible to create a script which would update the tables after the intial export of the data by using original script but just using the _060162016 extension at the end of each table. Does that help?

Comment: you should probably use dynamic sql query? appending the _060162016 part? select * from sysobjects  where xtype = 'u' gives you list of tables. From there you can work your way towards building dynamic query

Comment: Are you trying to copy the structure or data?

Comment: please post some code because both your requirement and your goal are not clear.

Comment: Here is some code for a table:

Comment: Here is some code for a table:  The part that I am having trouble figuring out is how can i get the latest table with (_1604190611) as extension to all the tables. otherwise the names will be the same except for _1604190611 changes.                                                                                                                                                                                              

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CLINMARK_1604190611](
 [MEMBER] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
 [RULEID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [MIN_DT] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
)